# Unable to save channels to PFInstallation

Tags: ios, parse-platform, channel

I'm trying to save multiple channels for the same user
But just keeps me first. Others do not save.

```
NSString *business =self.business.name;
    NSArray *subscribedChannels = [PFInstallation currentInstallation].channels;
    for (NSString *channel in subscribedChannels){
        NSLog(@"Channel %@ ",channel);
    }
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:business forKey:@"channels"];

    NSLog(@"Business : %@",business );

    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

When I go to the table of parse web , it is only created the first channel.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the sample data for the `subscribedChannels` and `business`. More importantly, is the code copied and what is `currentInstallation`?

Comment: Isn't it better to add all your channels in an array and add it to the currentInstallation using addUniqueObjectsFromArray function instead ?

Comment: PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];

the user has to choose companies and when you press a button you have to register the company in the channels.
You can be registered in several channels

Comment: The issue does not seem to be from the code above, I do not see anything wrong with it.

Comment: Encountered the samething here, surprised that there's not much answer to this one